# Modal ls not firing with V-Show

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a modal that is being imported and added to a page as a component. The modal is called into the page as

```
 <TwoFactorStatus v-show="showTwoFactoreModal"></TwoFactorStatus>
```

Then a button has a click event as such

```
 <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" @click="ShowTwoFactoreModal()" type="danger">Disable two-factor authentication</button>
```

Which then calls a method to

```
ShowTwoFactoreModal() {
      this.showTwoFactoreModal = true;
    }
```

The Modal looks like so

```
<template>
<div class="modal fade" id="showTwoFactoreModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                Two Factor Switch Off
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This modal must pass</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap i asume?

Comment: Yes using bootstrap

Comment: try toggling class fade rather than using v-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ShowTwoFactoreModal` function to something like this:

```js
ShowTwoFactoreModal() {
    this.showTwoFactoreModal = true;
    $('#showTwoFactoreModal').modal('show');
}
```

Either that or maybe using :class bindings and appending the active class, but this is more straight. I usually do it with an eventBus, but it might be overkill for your project... if you were to do it with an event bus, you could attach an eventListener to the modal component, and attach a showModal function callback to that listener where you don't need to set IDs you can just call it like: `$(this.$el).modal('show');` ... but thats another story...

Comment: The weird part is I have done modal's in other places on the site exactly the same way I did the above and never needed this bit     $('#showTwoFactoreModal').modal('show');
But it works great! Thank you

Comment: I might be wrong, but It's probably a CSS Classes issue, you probably have the required classes on the other modals and body and you just hide them with v-show, check this do this and other modals show without v-show, if the other modals are showing this is probably the case

Comment: I'll take a look and see what the differences are but thank you this one is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal is using its own js functions to handle show and hide modal. Vue v-show can only show and hide the components which you programmed its logic. But bootstrap modal is showing and hiding by appending class to modal component.
If you want to use without bootstrap.js to toggle you can use jQuery with Vue as below. (if just want show then change method .show())

```
//200 is duration of fade animation.
<button @click="toggleModal"></button>

function toggleModal() {
    $('#your_modal_id').fadeToggle(200)
}
```

If you want to use bootstrap own modal with their js then you can copy and paste modal code
here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

If you want Vue v-show to handle all process then write logic to do it. If need help just ask.